# asp.net, how to change text color to red in child nodes in VB codes?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I got everything worked now by list of server Name but I want to add a IF statement by checking a column from SQL Server called Compliance by either True or False value listed. If it False, the Name will change text color to Red. If it True, the Name won't change text color. I am not sure how add that in VB codes side. I am pretty sure that I would need to put IF statement inside **While dr.Read()**. I am pretty new to VB.Net and not sure which VB code that change text color.

Here is my VB codes,

```
Sub loadData()
    'clear treeview control
    TreeViewGroups.Nodes.Clear()

    'fetch owner data and save to in memory table
    Dim sqlConn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection((ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SOCT").ConnectionString))
    Dim strSqlSecondary As String = "SELECT [Name] FROM [dbo].[ServerOwners] where SecondaryOwner like @uid order by [name]"

    'Getting a list of True or False from Compliance column
    Dim strSqlCompliance As String = "SELECT [Compliance] FROM [dbo].[ServerOwners] where SecondaryOwner like @uid order by [name]"

    Dim cmdSecondary As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSqlSecondary, sqlConn)

    Dim cmdCompliance As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSqlCompliance, sqlConn)

    cmdSecondary.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", TNN.NEAt.GetUserID())

    cmdCompliance.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", TNN.NEAt.GetUserID())

    Dim dr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Try
        sqlConn.Open()
        Dim root As TreeNode
        Dim rootNode As TreeNode
        Dim firstNode As Integer = 0
        'Load Primary Owner Node
        'Create RootTreeNode

        dr = cmdSecondary.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            'Load Secondary Owner Node
            'Create RootTreeNode
            root = New TreeNode("Secondary Owner", "Secondary Owner")
            TreeViewGroups.Nodes.Add(root)
            root.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None

            rootNode = TreeViewGroups.Nodes(firstNode)
            'populate the child nodes
            While dr.Read()
                Dim child As TreeNode = New TreeNode(dr("Name"), dr("Name"))
                rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(child)
                child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None
            End While
            dr.Close()
            cmdSecondary.Dispose()
        End If

        'check if treeview has nodes
        If TreeViewGroups.Nodes.Count = 0 Then
            noServers()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        hide()
        PanelError.Visible = True
        LabelError.Text = ex.ToString()
    Finally
        sqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the compliance value can be converted to a Boolean value and then wrap a DIV around the text with the style of the color red, like this:

```
While dr.Read()
    Dim child As TreeNode = New TreeNode(dr("Name"), dr("Name"))

    ' Test whether compliance value can be converted to Boolean type or not
    Dim complianceFlag As Boolean 

    If Boolean.TryParse(dr("Compliance"), complianceFlag) Then
        ' Yes, compliance value is a Boolean, now set color based on value
        If Not complianceFlag Then
            child.Text = "<div style='color:Red; float: left;'>" + child.Text & "&lt;/div>"
        End If
    Else
        ' Unable to convert compliance value to Boolean
        ' Do something here if you want or just ignore it
    End If

    rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(child)
    child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None
End While
```

Note: `TryParse` will not throw an exception if the intended conversion fails, thus the need for the output variable of `complianceFlag`.

Comment: What about using ForeColor?

Comment: @StudentIT - the ASP.NET `TreeNode` control does not have a `ForeColor` property (read [TreeNode Class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode(v=vs.110).aspx)), but if it did then yes that would be a great suggestion. :-)

Comment: Make sense, however I got the blue underlined **child.Style** said that Style is not a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode

Comment: @StudentIT - okay, updated answer to use a DIV to wrap the tree node text and applied red color style to wrapper DIV.

Comment: I modified the code you edited and got the error message that said, `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Compliance at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)`

Comment: @StudentIT - well if the the field `Compliance` is not part of the result set, then yeah that is a problem. Have you confirmed that your query returns a field named `Compliance`?

Comment: I fixed it and it worked! However the Div tag seems to move the server Name line down instead of 1 line next to checkbox. I edited my working codes. Any idea why the red text move 1 line down?

Comment: @StudentIT - try floating the DIV to the left, see updated answer.

Comment: And what is **"&lt;/div>"** that you modified? It seems dosesn't do anything.

Comment: I tried by add `child.Text = "<div style='color:Red; float: left;'>" + child.Text & "</div>"`. It doesn't move back next to checkbox.

Comment: @StudentIT - The `&lt;/div>` comprises the closing DIV tag (`</div>`), it was taken from a C# translation of the code, I develop in C# normally and convert my code to VB.NET for VB.NET questions on here. C# has escapes characters that the `&lt;` syntax avoids.

Comment: @StudentIT - this is an add-on question, the CSS position issue is not related to the logic to change the color of the tree node. Please ask another question exclusively related to the DIV tag being pushed down one line. If you feel my answer helped you, then feel free to up-vote and/or accept the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got the code work

```
Sub loadData()
    'clear treeview control
    TreeViewGroups.Nodes.Clear()

    'fetch owner data and save to in memory table
    Dim sqlConn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection((ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SOCT").ConnectionString))
    Dim strSqlSecondary As String = "SELECT [Name], [Compliance] FROM [dbo].[ServerOwners] where SecondaryOwner like @uid order by [name]"

    Dim cmdSecondary As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSqlSecondary, sqlConn)


    cmdSecondary.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", TNN.NEAt.GetUserID())


    Dim dr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader


    Try
        sqlConn.Open()
        Dim root As TreeNode
        Dim rootNode As TreeNode
        Dim firstNode As Integer = 0
        'Load Secondary Owner Node
        'Create RootTreeNode    
        dr = cmdSecondary.ExecuteReader()

        If dr.HasRows Then
            'Load Secondary Owner Node
            'Create RootTreeNode
            root = New TreeNode("Secondary Owner", "Secondary Owner")
            TreeViewGroups.Nodes.Add(root)
            root.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None

            rootNode = TreeViewGroups.Nodes(firstNode)
            'populate the child nodes
            While dr.Read()
                Dim child As TreeNode = New TreeNode(dr("Name"), dr("Name"))
                Dim complianceFlag As Boolean

                If Boolean.TryParse(dr("Compliance"), complianceFlag) Then
                    ' Yes, compliance value is a Boolean, now set color based on value
                    If Not complianceFlag Then
                        child.Text = "<div style='color:Red'>" + child.Text & "</div>"
                    End If
                Else

                End If
                rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(child)
                child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None
            End While
            dr.Close()

            cmdSecondary.Dispose()

        End If


        'check if treeview has nodes
        If TreeViewGroups.Nodes.Count = 0 Then
            noServers()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        hide()
        PanelError.Visible = True
        LabelError.Text = ex.ToString()
    Finally
        sqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```